# How can I pass a URL with query parameters to another URL as a query param?

Tags: html, url, query-string

As per the subject, I'm trying to do this but it is being flagged as an invalid URL using the checking website: http://www.getlinkinfo.com/

An example of the type of URL I'm trying to validate is this:
`http://www.google.com/?link=www.yahoo.com?value=foobar`

This is in a similar format to what I'm trying to get working. I have tried encoding various parts but they all give the same results.

Encoding just the value doesn't work:
`http://www.google.com/?link=www.yahoo.com%3Fvalue%3Dfoobar`

Encoding the entire query param doesn't work:
`http://www.google.com/?link%3Dwww.yahoo.com%3Fvalue%3Dfoobar`

Encoding the entire URL doesn't work:
`http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%3Flink%3Dwww.yahoo.com%3Fvalue%3Dfoobar`

Does anyone know how the URL can be formatted such that it validates okay?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `encodeURI` method in JavaScript like this:

```
encodeURI("http://www.google.com/?link=www.yahoo.com%3Fvalue%3Dfoobar");
```

This will result into:

```
http://www.google.com/?link=www.yahoo.com%253Fvalue%253Dfoobar
```

And when you enter the result into the textbox on http://www.getlinkinfo.com, you'll get your URL as a valid one!

Comment: Thank you so much. How strange, I was using the website https://www.url-encode-decode.com/ to do the encoding and it was encoding the question mark to %3F but the fix above uses an encoding of %253F.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html), for example:

```
URLEncoder.encode("mysite.com?a=test&b=test", "UTF-8");
```

Should give you `mysite.com%2Fa%3Dtest%26b%3Dtest`

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers won't work when the url you want to pass as param (let's call it  url1) as more than one param:

```js
const url1 = 'https://example.com?param1=asd&param2=qwe';
const url2 = `https://otherexample.com?urlparam=${url1}`;

const urlObject = new URL(encodeURI(url2));

console.log(urlObject.searchParams.get('urlparam'));
// Outputs: https://example.com?param1=asd
```

With this method we actually create a this url:

```js
console.log(urlObject.toString());
// Outputs: https://otherexample.com?urlparam=https://example.com?param1=asd&param2=qwe`
```

It's not what we wanted because the `param2` parameter is now a parameter of `url2` instead of `url1`.

We can try:

```js
console.log(urlObject.searchParams.get('param2'));
// Outputs: qwe
```

---

Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instead:

```js
const url1 = 'https://example.com?param1=asd&param2=qwe';
const urlParam = new URLSearchParams({ urlparam: url1 });
const url2 = `https://otherexample.com?${urlParam}`;

const urlObject = new URL(url2);

console.log(urlObject.searchParams.get('urlparam'));
//Outputs: https://example.com?param1=asd&param2=qwe

console.log(urlObject.toString());
// Outputs: https://otherexample.com/?urlparam=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Fparam1%3Dasd%26param2%3Dqwe
```

---

You can also use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```js
console.log(encodeURI('https://example.com?param1=asd&param2=qwe'));
// Outputs: https://example.com?param1=asd&param2=qwe
```

And

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('https://example.com?param1=asd&param2=qwe'));
// Outputs: https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%3Fparam1%3Dasd%26param2%3Dqwe
```

Anyway I prefer to use URLSearchParams to avoid these kind of pitfalls.